# what is the solution of this error that i am facing with bean factory?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

**
Jun 29, 2021 9:45:18 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.8.Final} Jun 29, 2021 9:45:19 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found Jun 29, 2021 9:45:19 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager  INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final} Tue Jun 29 21:45:19 PKT 2021 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification. Jun 29, 2021 9:45:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 286 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 272 milliseconds ago. Jun 29, 2021 9:45:19 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect Jun 29, 2021 9:45:19 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null Jun 29, 2021 9:45:20 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factory' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'factory' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:878)   at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)  at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)   at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)    at com.springDb.App.main(App.java:17) Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:123)   at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:77)    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.initialize(MetamodelImpl.java:128)    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:297)    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:445)  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)  at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)  at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:616)     at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:600)  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853)     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790)    ... 12 more Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]     at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:91)    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:116)    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.(EntityMetamodel.java:385)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.(AbstractEntityPersister.java:519)  at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:124)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:96)    ... 22 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:78)  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:88)    ... 32 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @209da20d    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:357)    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199)    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193)    at javassist.util.proxy.SecurityActions.setAccessible(SecurityActions.java:103)     at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass2(FactoryHelper.java:181)  at javassist.util.proxy.FactoryHelper.toClass(FactoryHelper.java:164)   at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass3(ProxyFactory.java:507)    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass2(ProxyFactory.java:492)    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass1(ProxyFactory.java:428)    at javassist.util.proxy.ProxyFactory.createClass(ProxyFactory.java:400)     at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.postInstantiate(JavassistProxyFactory.java:72)  at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildProxyFactory(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:162)     at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:163)    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:58)     ... 38 more
**

**Here Is My config.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    name="ds">
    <property name="driverClassName"
        value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url"
        value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springjdbc" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    name="factory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.springDb.entities.Student</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>  
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate"
    name="hibernateTemplat">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory"></property>

</bean>
    <bean class="com.springDb.Dao.StudentDao" name="studentDao">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplat"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager"
        name="transactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="factory"></property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

**StudentDao class**

```
package com.springDb.Dao;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import com.springDb.entities.Student;

public class StudentDao {

private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

@Transactional
public int insert(Student student) {
    
    Integer r=(Integer)hibernateTemplate.save(student);
    return r;
}

public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
    return hibernateTemplate;
}

public void setHibernateTemplate(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
    this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
}

public StudentDao(HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
    super();
    this.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
}
public StudentDao() {


}}
```

**Student class**

```
package com.springDb.entities;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Student_Info")
public class Student {
@Id
@Column(name = "Student_Id")
private int studentId;
@Column(name = "Student_Name")
private String studentName;
@Column(name = "Student_City")
private String studentCity;

public Student(int studentId, String studentName, String studentCity) {
    super();
    this.studentId = studentId;
    this.studentName = studentName;
    this.studentCity = studentCity;
}



public Student() {

}

public int getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(int studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getStudentName() {
    return studentName;
}

public void setStudentName(String studentName) {
    this.studentName = studentName;
}

public String getStudentCity() {
    return studentCity;
}

public void setStudentCity(String studentCity) {
    this.studentCity = studentCity;
}

}
```

**App.java class**

```
package com.springDb;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.springDb.Dao.StudentDao;
import com.springDb.entities.Student;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
       ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
       StudentDao studentDao = context.getBean("studentDao",StudentDao.class);
       
       Student student=new Student(1233,"Hery","Turky");
      
       int r = studentDao.insert(student);
       System.out.println("Done"+r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever version of Spring/Hibernate you are using, it is not compatible with the Java version that you are using. Try updating Spring/Hibernate or use an older Java version.